# Get the last time a value has changed in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an employee database which contains records about employees. The fields are :

- `employee_identifier`
- `employee_salary`
- `date_of_the_record`

I would like to get, for each record, the date of the last change in `employee_salary`. Which SQL query could work ?

I have tried with multiple sub-queries, but it does not work.

Comment: I agree it would be a better question if you add sample data and sample results. Also, what you have tried so far and what issues you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(arr),
  (SELECT MAX(date_of_the_record) FROM UNNEST(arr)
    WHERE employee_salary != t.employee_salary
  ) AS last_change_in_employee_salary
FROM (
  SELECT *, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(employee_salary, date_of_the_record)) OVER(win) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.employee_database`
  WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY employee_identifier ORDER BY date_of_the_record)
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()`

```
with cte as
(
select *,
row_number()over(partition by employee_identifier order by date_of_the_record desc) rn from table_name
) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without a subquery.  If you want all the columns:

```
SELECT as value ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY date_of_the_record DESC LIMIT 1)[ordinal(1)]
FROM t t
GROUP BY employee_identifier;
```

If you just want the date, use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT employee_identifier, MAX(date_of_the_record)
FROM t t
GROUP BY employee_identifier;
```

Comment: What I want to get is the date of the last change in salary. Does your query give this ?